# Login freeze after reboot

Tags: login, freeze

My problem started after i rebooted my pc from the terminal , not doing any upgrades ,just a simple reboot , i saw some warning about low space on the home folder nothing else but i think it is unlikely that this is the problem . My computer booted just fine ,but when i type my login password it freezes and nothing happens . I can't acces tty shell with CTRL+ALT+F(1...6) ,when i do this sometimes it loads all that output and keeps bring me the login screen and freezes , i managed to get to a login in tty once put after i type my password it reloading the login screen . I have installed on this machine a fluxbox windows manager and i could login there , and list my files and did some commands i saw on related problem posts , don't know if it's stupid or not .. tried reinstall ubuntu-desktop , unity what . nothing works for me ..

Comment: How'd you do the "simple reboot" from the terminal?

Comment: i've just typed the reboot command ..

Comment: If you didn't use the `--force` option that should "arrange for the system to be brought down in a safe way"... maybe a filesystem got corrupted somehow anyway. Tried to `fsck` them?

Comment: i would not like to take that step says it's possible to damage my file system for is being mounted ... i don't want to lose my data .. i can see my files from the fluxbox enviroment with the ls command , not see them on desktop .. could be something with the other enviroment (primary one )..

Comment: `fsck` should check & *fix* the filesystem. There is a way to have it do a check at next reboot, since running it on a mounted FS isn't good. Or run a live DVD/USB and `fsck` the unmounted partitions from there. Can use the `-n` option for most FS's (msdos, ext) to do a check only too.

Comment: i don't know why can't i use tty .. from there i could try and solve the problem but like this ..

Comment: My filesystem is "full" and won't boot right.  I am booted into an ubuntu USB.  How can I clear out space and restore my working filesystem?

Comment: Please follow @Xen2050's instructions.  Boot from a LiveCD, then run `parted --list` and post the output back here and we'll tell you exactly what you'll have to do so you will not lose any files.  And if you're scared of Xen2050, read [this Q&A by me](http://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc).  I'm **Mr. Backup-Your-Files!** here!  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

Could be that being **out of space** is causing all the problems... that's the first error you mention, so should be the first thing fixed.
or a filesystem (FS) problem...
or there's some error in the GUI desktop...

But running from a live USB/DVD is the first step, to:

- Check the FS for errors -  [**Note:** if your hard drive is failing, then it will probably get worse no matter what, a whole-partition backup with `gddrescue` may be required, then fix & backup from the copy]

  To do a read-only check (if you're really paranoid about losses, but you should already have several backups in that case).

  ```
  fsck -nv /dev/<device>
  ```

  But you're probably using an ext3/4 filesystem on `/` & `/home`, so `fsck` would use the **`e2fsck`** program, and these options would be useful:

  - `-n`      Open the filesystem read-only, and assume an answer of 'no' to  all  questions.
  - `-f`     Force checking even if the file system seems clean.
  - `-p`     Automatically repair ("preen") the file system.  This  option  will  cause
          e2fsck  to  automatically  fix  any filesystem problems that can be safely
          fixed without human intervention.
  - `-v`     Verbose mode.
- Mount the partitions - as read-only (`mount -o ro <partition> <mountpoint>`) if you're concerned about them getting changed.
- **Back up your files** - Copy wanted files to some other partition, delete unwanted ones, to solve the out of space problem and prevent catastrophic loss in case there is a problem in the future.
- Remove/re-install packages from a `chroot` environment (but if you can boot into single-user mode with networking that might be easier.
- Even re-install if you think the errors are too serious to overcome.